# Jquery on change of one dropdown second drop down is not loading

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

I have 2 dropdowns. My issue is I am getting html on ajax call, but html is not adding in second dropdown. Can someone help me figure out what I am missing here.

```
<select class="chosen-select form-control" name="country" id="country-list" data-placeholder="Choose a Country..." onChange="getState(this.value);">
<option value="">-Select Country-</option>
<?php
if(!empty($allCountries))
{
foreach($allCountries as $country)
{
?>
<option value="<?php echo $country['id']; ?>"<?php if(isset($countryData['id']) && $countryData['id']==$country['id']){ echo 'selected'; } ?>><?php echo $country['name']; ?></option>
<?php 
}
}
?>
</select>

<select class="chosen-select form-control" name="state" id="state-list">
<option value="">-Select State-</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
function getState(val) {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "utils/countrystatelist.php",
    data:'country_id='+val,
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
        $('#state-list').html(data);
        

    }
   });
   }
  </script>
```

Comment: You'll need to re-initialise `chosen` for the `select` (assuming `data` is just `<option>..` and not the whole `<select>`).  Get it working without the 3rd-party overlay first.

Comment: try `$("#form_field").trigger("chosen:updated");` to update your values. Read more [here](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)

Comment: @Pirate Where does that code come from? What form field and what kind of construct is  `"chosen:updated"` that one might trigger?

Comment: @mplungjan OP has `chosen-select` class on select. So it is based on the assumption that he has `chosen` library for dropdown. As per the [documentation](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/#change-update-events), when the options are updated in select, we need to explicitly tell `chosen` to refresh the list. It should be `$("#state-list").trigger("chosen:updated");`

Comment: Aha. That was a leap I had not taken  -I tagged it chosen for him now